# Kernel panic when booting directly from UEFI

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel, uefi

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 using debootstrap (without ubiquity). I'd like to be able to boot it directly from UEFI boot menu, without GRUB.

I have:

- confirmed that the kernel (4.13.0-32-generic) was build with EFI stub
- copied kernel and initrd to the ESP
- created UEFI boot menu entries using efibootmgr and using EFI shell
- double- and triple-checked all paths
- tried using 4.4.0-113 kernel
- tried providing the `root=` option via device name and UUID
- ran `update-initramfs`

Each time I end up with a kernel panic:

```
md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect
md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
md: autorun ...
md: ... autorun DONE.
VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

(Yes, there are no partitions listed. ESP should be /dev/sda2, `/` on /dev/sda5)

The system boots fine using GRUB (installed by another instance of Ubuntu on another partition). Suprisingly, it also boots fine from the EFI shell!

```
Shell> fs1:\path\vmlinuz.efi root=/dev/sda5 rw initrd=\path\initrd.img
```

Here's the efibootmgr command that creates failing entries:

```
efibootmgr -p 2 -c -g -L "Ubuntu Rescue" -l \\EFI\\ubuntu-rescue\\vmlinuz.efi -u "root=/dev/sda5 rw initrd=\\EFI\\ubuntu-rescue\\initrd.img"
```

What am I missing?

**Update:** I have created a VirtualBox VM with a virtual ESP and attached physical partition to it. Then I set up the ESP the same way I did on my actual ESP.

After configuring boot entries using efibootmgr, Ubuntu booted successfully from the UEFI boot menu. So it appears that the issue is system-specific.

Is it possible that the kernel is missing a driver for my laptop's storage controller? It's a Dell Latitude E5450 laptop based on Intel's 5th gen platform.

**Update 2:** I've installed a regular Ubuntu Server on that partition (using a VM) to rule out debootstrap-related issues. The problem persists. System is still fully bootable in VM, but doesn't boot directly from bare-bone UEFI (does from EFI shell, though).

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Dell Inspiron 7567 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: @Mos I found out that it's an issue with Dell UEFIs, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that this is a common problem with Dell UEFIs - they don't seem to pass parameters to the EFI loader. Thus UEFI launches kernel using its EFI stub, but it's missing initrd and fails to boot.

I don't have any sources at hand currently, but this seems to be a common problem and it's probably googlable for those interested.

Workarounds include:

- Using an EFI shell script that will run automatically when shell boots. (there's also a timeout, so shell is still usable if necessary)
- Using systemd-boot, which is an EFI-aware bootloader which can boot kernels using their EFI stubs. Pop_OS combines this nicely with [kernelstub](https://github.com/isantop/kernelstub) in its default configuration, removing the need for GRUB2 altogether.
- It's probably possible to embed parameters or even entire initrd in the kernel image, but that sounds like a hassle.